# update fields in object with angular

Tags: angular

I have an object in database with these fields:
isRed, isToday, isImportant - all of them booleans, and an Id.

in my UI i have 3 checkboxes with inputs in my ts file
how can I update the object?
I have tried to create a new item and send it to the service
the thing is that i want to be able to send only one field, 2 or 3. not all of them at once

html code:

```
    <div class="mb-2 alternate-warning-checkbox-wrapper">
      <mdb-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isRed" [default]="false">isRed</mdb-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2 alternate-warning-checkbox-wrapper">
       <mdb-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isToday" [default]="false">isToday</mdb-checkbox>
     </div>
     <div class="mb-2 alternate-warning-checkbox-wrapper">
       <mdb-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isImportant " [default]="false">isImportant</mdb-checkbox>
     </div>
  <button type="button" mdbBtn class="btn-sm" (click)="updateSupplier()" color="dark-green" mdbWavesEffect>Save</button>
```

ts code:

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { SupplierService } from '@app/_core/api/supplier.service';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
        })
        export class App implements OnInit {
          @Input() isRed: boolean;
          @Input() isToday: boolean;
          @Input() isImportant : boolean;

          constructor(
            private itemService: ItemService,
          ) {

     }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

      updateSupplier() {
       let item = [this.isRed,
this.isToday,
this.isImportant
 ];
        this.itemService.updateItem(item)
      }

    }
```

service:

```
  updateItem(item: Item) {
    return this.apiService.put(`${this.resourceUrl}/update`, supplier);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set properties of Item to nullable and also your server should accept them as null.

```
class Item: {isRed?: boolean, isToday?: boolean, isImportant?: boolean}
```

in your ts file:

```
this.itemService.updateItem({isBoolean: this.isBoolean})
```

then in service you can check if all props was null then don't send any request